# Saving CubePermission to SSAS through AMO

Tags: c#, .net, ssas

In C# I have an object of type `CubePermission` of which I set the expressions on the `CellPermissions`. When it comes time to saving to the cube, I never see the changes. All I'm doing is this

```
CubePermission cubePermission = new CubePermission (...);

...
...

cubePermission.Update();
```

Whenever I check the `Cell Data` options in the role properties in SQL Management Studio, I don't see the changes I've done to the Role. How do I simply save my changes to my cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Whenever setting `Cell Data` security, especially if you need to set any `Read` or `ReadContingent` `CellPermissions`, you need to set the `Read` property to true on the `CubePermission` object. Then call the `Update()`.